# How do I add multiple copies of the same String to an existing ArrayList?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, initialization

I have an `ArrayList<String>`. I want to add n copies of a new `String` to it.

I've Googled generally and searched on StackOverflow. I've looked at the documentation.

Surely there's a better way than doing a loop?

I was hoping for something like:

```
myArray.addAll (ArrayList<String>(count: 10, value: "123"))
```

Comment: The reason I didn't put the `myArray` line as code, is because it's not *actual* code that someone could copy/paste into their kotlin project. But, whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize a `List` with a given size `n` and an initializer function like this:

```
fun main() {
    val n = 10
    val defaultList = List(n) { it -> "default" }  // you can leave "it ->" here
    println(defaultList)
}
```

This piece of code then outputs

```
[default, default, default, default, default, default, default, default, default, default]
```

If you want to intialize an `Array<String>` directly without using a `List` as intermediate, you can do

```
val defaultArray: Array<String> = Array(n) { "default" }
println(defaultArray.contentToString())
```

in the `main` and get the same output (even without the `it ->`, which, indeed, isn't necessary in this case).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I knew there'd be an answer. I still haven't mastered closures yet.

Comment: So, to complete my answer, I have `myArray.addAll (List (count) { "value" }`. The "it ->" is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Nice, glad it helped... And yes, the `it ->` isn't necessary... You can fill up an `Array` directly, see the last edit of my answer.